# Is it possible to get two IPv6 networks to communicate over IPv4 Internet in this case?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, ipv6, tunnel

I have a setup of a laptop connected to a cellular IPv4 network (3G usb dongle) and PC connected to another IPv4/IPv6 network. Both have been configured to run as IPv6 routers and each has its IPv6 network.

The laptop connects to the Internet via the 3G network with IPv4 address (private one and it is mostly changing) on one interface and has the other interface on AP mode providing its own private IPv6 network (2001:db8:444::/64). The PC connects to the Internet via the organization network with both public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on one interface and has the other interface on AP mode providing its own private IPv6 network (2001:db8:222::/64). Both running Linux Ubuntu.

Is it possible to get the two IPv6 network (2001:db8:222::/64 and 2001:db8:444::/64) to communicate over the IPv4 Internet?

Is openvpn of any good in this case to get IPv6 traffic over IPv4-IPv4 tunnel?

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. You will need to encapsulate the IPv6 packets in IPv4 packets in conjuction with a tunnel.

Comment: Great, so any idea on how to achieve that in Linux

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/623732/is-it-possible-in-this-case-to-get-two-ipv6-networks-to-communicate-over-the-ipv

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* method would be to set up a VPN over IPv4 – for example, OpenVPN in 'tap' (L2) mode.

- On site 1 (organization):

  ```
  # /etc/openvpn/<site2>.conf
  port 22
  float

  secret /etc/private/openvpn-<site1>-<site2>.key
  dev tap-<site2>
  route-up /etc/openvpn/<site2>-configure.sh
  script-security 2
  ```

  ```
  # /etc/openvpn/<site2>.sh
  ip link set $dev up
  ip addr add 2001:db8:111::1/64 dev $dev
  ip route add 2001:db8:222::/64 dev $dev
  (optional) ip route add ::/0 dev $dev
  ```
- On site 2 (laptop), practically the same:

  ```
  # /etc/openvpn/<site1>.conf
  remote <site1>-server.example.com 22
  nobind

  secret /etc/private/openvpn-<site1>-<site2>.key
  dev tap-<site1>
  route-up /etc/openvpn/<site1>-configure.sh
  script-security 2
  ```

  ```
  # /etc/openvpn/<site1>-configure.sh
  ip link set $dev up
  ip addr add 2001:db8:222::1/64 dev $dev
  ip route add 2001:db8:111::/64 dev $dev
  ```

Use `openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/private/openvpn-site2.key` to create the encryption key on your laptop, then copy it to the org. This setup only works for single-client connections, but is very simple to configure, without having to deal with TLS certificates.

---

If both peers had static IP addresses, you could use the built-in Linux IP-in-IP tunnel features.

The technically simplest method would be an IPv6-over-v4 tunnel, the exact same type as used by various IPv6 tunnel brokers – just with a more specific route.

```
ip tunnel add tunnel-site2 mode sit local <local-ipv4> remote <remote-ipv4>
```

Another type is a GRE tunnel, the kind used by PPTP. The syntax is the same, just with `mode gre`.

Once you have a tunnel interface, you can assign it an IPv6 address and/or configure routes.

Unfortunately, they have no option to deal with dynamically changing client IP addresses.

Comment: I have followed the same steps you have explained to create a VPN over ipv4 using OpenVPN tap mode but I could not ping the network connected to the server = 2001:db8:222::1 from the client (the laptop). it reports that address is unreachable as it send neighbour solicitation message but it gets no reply.